# Android escape characters in string

Tags: java, android, escaping

As per [json documenation](http://json.org/) some characters should be escaped using the backslash, otherwise, the server responds with some sort of error: `"Invalid JSON syntax"`.

To convert a string to JSON format string with escaped characters I use the following implementation:

```
private String getEscapedString(String value) {
    try {
        String str = JSONObject.quote(value);
        return str.substring(1,str.length()-1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As a result, it converts `"` to `\"`, `\` to `\\` and so forth.

But I believe it is not the best approach to escape characters in the string. Could you please suggest a better solution for escaping characters?

Answer (score 0):

You can send `JsonObject` to the server so there is no escape character in that.

For example, if our JSON to send be like this

```
{"filter": {}}
```

then JsonObject  will be

```
JsonObject jsonObjectmain = new JsonObject();
JsonObject jsonObjectitems = new JsonObject();
jsonObjectmain.add("filter", jsonObjectitems);
```